# R ggplot: Combine a barplot and a line chart from a long dataset

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a wide dataset that records the blood glucose values from 10 subjects.

```
library(dplyr) 

df_wide = data.frame(
  ID = seq(1, 10),
  gender = sample(0:1, 10, replace = T),
  glucose_0 = sample(100:125, 10, replace = T),
  glucose_60 = sample(180:200, 10, replace = T),
  glucose_120 = sample(130:160, 10, replace = T),
  glucose_180 = sample(100:125, 10, replace = T)
)
```

I then transformed it into a long dataset using `gather`:

```
df_long = df_wide %>% 
  gather("glucose_0", "glucose_60", "glucose_120", "glucose_180", key = Time, value = glucose) %>% 
  arrange(ID)
```

To show how the glucose values changed from 0 min to 180 min, I then made the following line chart:

```
df_long %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Time, y = glucose, group = ID)) + 
  geom_line(aes(linetype = as.factor(gender))) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_classic() +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("glucose_0", "glucose_60", "glucose_120", "glucose_180"),
                   labels = c("0", "60", "120", "180")) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  labs(
    x = "Time",
    y = "Glucose",
    fill = "Gender"
  )
```

Finally, to show the glucose at each time point, I also made a barplot:

```
df_long %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Time, y = glucose, fill = as.factor(gender))) + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = position_dodge()) +
  theme_classic() +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("glucose_0", "glucose_60", "glucose_120", "glucose_180"))
```

My question is: How to combine the line chart and the barplot into one figure that looks like this?
[image: Goal]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to plot the mean glucose levels as both bar and line

```
df_long %>%
  group_by(gender, Time) %>% 
  mutate(glucose = mean(glucose)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Time, y = glucose, fill = as.factor(gender))) + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = position_dodge()) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype=as.factor(gender), group=ID)) +
  theme_classic() +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("glucose_0", "glucose_60", "glucose_120", "glucose_180"))
```

[image]

Comment: In the final figure, I would like to see only two lines - showing the group mean glucose values, that correspond to the two bars at each time point. Does this help?

Comment: Do you realize that your bar plot ("I also made  a bar plot") does not show the mean glucose levels by gender at each time point. You have designed it to show the maximum glucose levels by gender at each time point.  I've edited my response to show mean.

Comment: now you should be able to see that the lines correspond to the top(s) of the bars

Comment: I didn't realize the bars were showing the max instead of average which I wanted, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for such a solution?

```
library(tidyverse)

df_wide %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    starts_with("glucose")
  ) %>% 
  mutate(gender = fct_inorder(factor(gender))) %>% 
  arrange(ID) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = name, y = value)) + 
  geom_col(aes(fill = gender, group=gender), width = 0.5, position = position_dodge())+
  stat_summary(aes(group = gender), fun = mean, geom = 'line', size=1, alpha=0.9) +
  stat_summary(aes(group = gender), fun = mean, geom = 'point', size=2, alpha=0.9) +
  theme_classic() +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("glucose_0", "glucose_60", "glucose_120", "glucose_180"),
                   labels = c("0", "60", "120", "180")) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  labs(
    x = "Time",
    y = "Glucose",
    fill = "Gender"
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Almost! Any chance that the two lines can be continuous? Each of them looks disconnected between time points.

Comment: Please see my update.

Comment: looks good @TarJae, but as I commented below, the bars show the max within timepoint and gender, which is fine as long as that is what is desired.

Comment: What should the bars show ?